# Error installing native Node.js add-on with node-gyp on Apple M1 (Big Sur)

Tags: node.js, xcode, node-gyp, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I'm using `yarn` to install packages including [asset-hash](https://github.com/sebastian-software/asset-hash), which depends on [metrohash](https://github.com/robertklep/node-metrohash).

I constantly run in the following error:

```
yarn install v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[-/11] ⠠ waiting...
[10/11] ⠠ metrohash
error /Users/johndoe/Projects/my-project/node_modules/metrohash: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/johndoe/Projects/my-project/node_modules/metrohash
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.10.0 | darwin | arm64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/johndoe/Projects/my-project/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/johndoe/Projects/my-project/node_modules/metrohash/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/johndoe/Projects/my-project/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/johndoe/.node-gyp/15.10.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/johndoe/.node-gyp/15.10.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/johndoe/Projects/my-project/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/johndoe/.node-gyp/15.10.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/johndoe/Projects/my-project/node_modules/metrohash',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-msse4.2' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/metrohash/src/metrohash_wrapper.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/metrohash/src/metrohash128.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-msse4.2' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/metrohash/src/metrohash128crc.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-msse4.2' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from ../src/metrohash128crc.cpp:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/nmmintrin.h:15:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/smmintrin.h:13:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/tmmintrin.h:13:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/pmmintrin.h:13:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/emmintrin.h:13:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:13:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:33:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:33:5: note: '__builtin_isless' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:33:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
                        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:50:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:67:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si'
    return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si((__v2si)__m, 0);
           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:129:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packsswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:159:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packssdw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:189:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packuswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:216:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:239:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:260:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:287:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:310:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:331:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_punpckldq'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:352:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddb'; did you mean '__builtin_arm_addg'?
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:352:19: note: '__builtin_arm_addg' declared here
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:352:19: error: first argument of MTE builtin function must be a pointer ('__v8qi' (vector of 8 'char' values) invalid)
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:373:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddw'; did you mean '__builtin_arm_addg'?
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:352:19: note: '__builtin_arm_addg' declared here
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:373:19: error: first argument of MTE builtin function must be a pointer ('__v4hi' (vector of 4 'short' values) invalid)
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:394:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_paddd'; did you mean '__builtin_arm_addg'?
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:352:19: note: '__builtin_arm_addg' declared here
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:394:19: error: first argument of MTE builtin function must be a pointer ('__v2si' (vector of 2 'int' values) invalid)
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
                  ^                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/metrohash/src/metrohash128crc.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/johndoe/Projects/my-project/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/johndoe/.nvm/versions/node/v15.10.0/bin/node" "/Users/johndoe/Projects/my-project/node_modules/metrohash/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/johndoe/Projects/my-project/node_modules/metrohash
```

I'm using

- MacBook Pro, Apple M1
- macOS Big Sur, 11.2.2
- node 15.10.0
- yarn 1.22.10

What I've tried so far

- tried other node versions 12 and 14
- ran `xcode-select --install`, removed the tool and reinstalled it
- ran `brew update` and `brew upgrade`
- executed the Terminal using Rosetta

I think the error could be related to the Apple M1 chip or the latest Big Sur update.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a M1 problem.  Have you asked the package maintaines?

Comment: No, I haven't. The package metrohash hasn't been updated for 2 year. My colleague says he can build it and is on an M1 too. He uses Big Sur 11.0.1 though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of a colleague I could fix the error.

I had to uninstall brew and reinstall it using Rosetta. Then I reinstalled node and yarn also using the Terminal in Rosetta mode.

Comment: This is only a workaround to emulate everything in x86_64...

Answer (score 5):

Please compare the node-sass version with your node version

[image]

Comment: Node sure why `node-sass` is mentioned here

Answer (score 2):

I got the same errors on `macOS 12.5 Monterey` with `M1 Pro`. This was the solution for me:

1. Delete `node_modules`
2. Remove `node-sass` from `package.json`
3. `yarn install`
4. `yarn add node-sass`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on macOS 12.1 Monterey which was being caused by node-sass-chokidar.  The issue arose for me when I switched from an older NodeJS to version 16 LTS.

To fix the issue I:

1. removed node-sass-chokidar from package.json
2. deleted node_modules
3. did a yarn install
4. added node-sass with yarn add node-sass

I also needed to change these lines in "scripts" of package.json.

From:

"build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",

To:

"build-css": "node-sass --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",

After doing that everything has ran fine.
There is talk about the efficiency of using node-sass over node-sass-chokidar (https://pretagteam.com/question/remove-nodesass-from-my-react-project-which-uses-createreactapp) just for completeness but it does not seem to have affected my setup.